# The final exams "have started", "have been started" or "are started"?

Tags: grammar, difference, tense

It kinda confuses me; so I wanted it to be cleared out for me: 
Is it

- the final exams have started
- the final exams have been started or
- the final exams are started

Which one is the correct form and what are the differences?
ok. I am having exams at the moment and I have only had one exam so far. I just want to tell this friend that the exams have started. that's it. I'm just not sure if it's correct or not

Comment: Hello and welcome! You should add a bit about your own research and thoughts. We will be happy to help, but we will not do the work *for* you. You might want to have a look at his: meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please. One hint on an answer: context is crucial and 3. is plain wrong due to singular/plural mismatch.

Comment: hello.thanks for editing the question. it looks way better .haha ;-)

Comment: I just changed "is" to "are" :)

Comment: John you forgot about the question title!

Comment: We would need to understand what you are trying to say before we can tell you which one is the correct form. What are your thoughts about the differences between the tenses? If we understand what you're thinking we can give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional information - I've retracted my close vote. I don't have time to write a good answer right now, but I will later if no-one beats me to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, you would say this:

> Final exams have started. (or begun)

"Final exams" doesn't need an article here since you're talking about final exams in general. You would only say "the final exams" if you wanted to talk about a specific group of exams.

> The final exams have been started.

This means that someone or something caused the final exams to start. This is unusual. In English, final exams are an event, not a process or machine.

> The final exams are started.

A native speaker would probably understand this, but it's bad grammar. You could say "Final exams are starting", but that doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: I'll add that "The final exams have been started" has a form of the verb "to be" in it, which is what makes it passive tense.  That's why it means that someone or something caused them to start.

Answer (score -1):

All  statements of your are right.

1. Final exams have started (its intransitive use of verb "to start"
2. Final exams have been started(its like.....started in the past and
   still going on. here "started" is an adjective.) This sentence works
   as passive sentence also.however, for that it requires some context.
3. Final exam is started (its present fact.here" started" works as
   adjective again)

So you can say it anyway.....as you wish.

Comment: It simply isn't idiomatic to say "is started" in a case like this if the sentence ends there. We would only really use that with a prepositional phrase afterwards, like "with great fanfare" or "by starting pistol" (which would be weird, but whatever). This is because the use of the simple present here would basically only be used for making a general statement, not to talk about a present fact.

Comment: Mem,then what about I am tired.(its present fect)here tired acts as adjective.....same way   exam is started.

Comment: We don't use *started* as an adjective anywhere near as much as we do *tired*. If you see *started*, and it could be an adjective or a verb, it's almost always a verb. That may be dialect dependent, though. In British English, and I think most American English, *started* is generally a verb.

Comment: Men one more question....supposing I am trying to start the computer but its not started/its not starting then what do I say....? The computer is not starting/ computer is not getting(being)started...pls guide me....